# DataTables sort mixed numeric and text column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I am trying to construct a DataTable sortable table that contains a column of numbers, but this column also contains the text `NA` to denote missing data. I was wondering how I would write a custom sorting function so that when I sort on the column the `NA`s come up AFTER the numbers rather than before when listing values greatest to smallest. Codepen here: https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/VwKJeMo

```js
$('#my-table').DataTable({
            "autoWidth": false,
            "order": []
        });
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

table {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Nr. </th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Carl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Alan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Bobby</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Maya</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Jordan</td>
    </tr>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>Monica</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Desired Output:

When sorting from largest to smallest value:

```html
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Nr. </th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Bobby</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Alan</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Carl</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Maya</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Jordan</td>
    </tr>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>Monica</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data), which lets you store a custom sorting value, which is different from the display value:

```js
$('#my-table').DataTable( {
  columnDefs: [ { 
    targets: [ 0 ], 
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      if ( type === 'sort' ) {
        var sortValue = data;
        switch( data ) {
          case '-':
            sortValue = -999998;
            break;
          case 'NA':
            sortValue = -999999
            break;
          default: // already set, in this case
        } 
        return sortValue;
      } else { 
        return data;
      }
  }
  } ]
} );
```

This assumes you will never have numeric values lower than the two values used in the `switch` statement. You can adjust as needed, if your overall data is not compatible with this.

My sample:

[image]